# opencv execution time for convert rgb to hsv

Tags: performance, opencv, binary, rgb, hsv

I'm trying to run a camera at 30fps, and do image processing at similar speeds. For images of size 640 x 480, using `cvCvtColor` to convert the RGB image to HSV haves the processing time to about 15fps.

Right now, the user has to be able to specify 2 HSV values and the program should return a binary image of all pixels within that range.

So right now, I convert the whole image to HSV space using cvCvtColor and use cvInRangeS.

**How can make decrease the processing time to reach 30fps?**

I am using vc2010 with opencv

Comment: Can you post some profiling results? This seems to be too much to be real.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a look-up table for RGB-Values (just an array with 256**3 entries for an 8UC3 image) and check each incoming pixel against this table.

Another approach would be to just check every 9th (or something like that) pixel of your input image and dilate your output mask. If you want to detect colors, then adjacent pixels will have a very similar color very often so that the output images will look very similar.

Comment: if source data  is in 8/8/8 int bits, one option is to spend 16Mbytes for lookup table . that larger than cache   produces signifant CPU stall even 16777216 is way huge for that lead to bottleneck ??? this is possible to do that .

Comment: for secound approach cant understand it i want only convert from rgb to hsv and then thresholding it to binary image
 the dilate operation for binary img or for rgb img ??

Comment: If you think that a 16MB table is too large, just create a lookup-table only for even values of R, G and B. You use just a little precision and the table is only 2MB large.  For the second approach: you just check if every 9th pixel ( (for (int x=0; x<width; x+=2)...)  has the right color and mark these pixels in your output image. You then dilate that image to fill the gaps between the ckecked pixels.